# What is the origin of the phrase "hate your guts"?

Tags: etymology, phrases, expressions

Where does the phrase "hate your guts" (for example "I hate your guts") come from?

I've heard the phrase used as a way to convey extreme and deep dislike of another individual. However, it seems strange to have just been born arbitrarily and I suspect there is a source.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Dictionaries

The Shorter Slang Dictionary (1994) says:

> **hate (sb's) guts** to dislike (sb) intensely. Adopted from the USA around 1937.

The *[New Partridge Dictionary of Slang and Unconventional English](http://books.google.com/books?id=cCVnlIUTpg4C&pg=PA324&dq=hate%20guts%20dictionary&hl=en&sa=X&ei=zKdeUe28IIiLswbXvoDQBQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=hate%20guts%20dictionary&f=false)* (2008) says:

> **guts** *noun* **1** the stomach; the general area of the stomach and intestines. Standard English from late C14; slipped into unconventional usage early in C19 *UK, 1393*. **2** the essentials, the important part, the inner and real meaning *UK, 1663*.

And:

> **hate someone's guts** to hate someone intensely *UK, 1918*

The *Historical Dictionary of American Slang* has a similar "I hate his intestines" from 1901, and according to chief editor [Jonathan Lighter](http://listserv.linguistlist.org/cgi-bin/wa?A2=ind1304A&L=ads-l&P=R3817): "*Guts* being regarded in that far-off age as rather vulgar."

### Antedating

I found a 1913 (and possibly 1912) antedating. *[Within The Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Within_the_Law_%281923_film%29)* was a Broadway production in 1912, written by [Bayard Veiller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayard_Veiller). Here's an extract from the **1913** [book based on the play](http://archive.org/details/withinthelaw00danarich) ([plain text](http://archive.org/details/withinthelaw00danarich) / [full view](http://archive.org/stream/withinthelaw00danarich#page/n346/mode/1up)) "by Marvin Dana from the play of Bayard Veiller":

> "Was there any bad feeling between you and Eddie 
>   Griggs?"
>
> Garson's reply was explicit.
>
> "Never till that very minute. Then, I learned the 
>   truth about what he'd framed up with you." The speaker's 
>   voice reverted to its former fierceness in recollection, 
>   of the treachery of one whom he had trusted.
>
> **"He was a stool-pigeon, and I hated his guts! That's 
>   all,"** he concluded, with brutal candor.

The same line appears in [1917](http://archive.org/details/melodramafour00veilrich) [books](http://archive.org/details/withinlawamelod00veilgoog) [of](http://archive.org/details/withinlawmelodra00veil) the script, and I expect it was also in the original production which was first performed at Eltinge Theatre, New York, September 11th 1912.

Via [ADS-L](http://listserv.linguistlist.org/cgi-bin/wa?A2=ind1304A&L=ads-l&P=R3881) is a **1911** found by Garson O'Toole:

> [ref] 1911 June 3, Seattle Daily Times, Stenographic Report of Today's Testimony, Quote Page 8, Column 6, Seattle, Washington.(GenealogyBank)[/ref]
>
> [Begin excerpt] You further said: "I hope I may never see my mother alive if I ever gave the ---- a cent. I never had use for him, and I hate his guts." [End excerpt]
>
> (The dashes above represent a single long dash.)

Answer (score 6):

*Guts* is used in many expressions and always refers to something fundamental about a person. These are just [a few](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/gut), there are many others:

> *a gut feeling:* a feeling that you are certain is right, even if you cannot explain why. "My gut feeling was that she was lying."
>
> *a gut reaction:*  a reaction that is based on your immediate feelings about someone or something "When a tragedy like this happens, I think people's gut reaction is anger and a desire to find someone to blame."
>
> *have your guts for garters*  (British informal):  if you say that you will have someone's guts for garters, you mean that you intend to punish them very severely.  "If I catch you smoking again I'll have your guts for garters."

It's similar to expressions using *stomach* relating to physical ability or courage:

> I didn't have the stomach to see him, knowing what he'd done.

Compare:

> “He which hath no stomach to this fight, Let him depart;" [Shakespeare
>   Henry V]

and

> He had the guts to stand up and say what he thought.

Just as the heart is the metaphorical seat of emotions, so *guts* are linked to deep, instinctive feelings and reactions. So to say you *hate someone's guts* is to say you hate them to the very core.

Comment: And don't forget _bowels_, as in _bowels of mercy_, _bowels of compassion_, and, perhaps best known, the Apostle's phrase “in the bowels of Jesus Christ" in his epistle to the Philippians, most famously borrowed by Oliver Cromwell for use in his letter to the Synod of the Church of Scotland, “I beseech you, in the bowels of Christ, think it possible that you may be mistaken."

Answer (score 0):

I have no background in languages; but thought I'd add my two cents. Use of the word "guts" to describe feelings that are go to our core is clear. Aside from location and disgusting visual appearance, there may be also be an association with the abdominal gripping sensation our bodies feel when our nervous system kicks in.

Comment: Your theory doesn't explain the origin of hating somebody else's guts.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage! Please explain your answer, preferably with some supporting statements and references. While opinions are valued, they are not of much help as answers.

Answer (score -1):

I would venture this:  When we hate someone, we hate them through and through . . . that is, their heart, their soul, their mind.  If we HATE THEIR GUTS, it is to go a major step further, that is, hating the basest/vilest part of the individual, which thus takes the hatred to the most loathsome degree.

Comment: While an interesting suggestion, this site tends to prefer answers that provide some sort of support [citations or, perhaps, personal recollection provided they are acknowledged as such]. Can you offer evidence of this?

Comment: [as an aside, if you're right, it's more that your attitude is *imputing* that baseness or vileness, no?]

Answer (score -2):

Although I don't have any good evidence to back it up, I've heard it argued that the term came from archaeologists in Egypt finding heiroglyphs depicting old scores being settled by destroying the preserved organs of the person to be disgraced - leading to the term "hate your guts".

Whatever the answer, this NGram appears to show that the term is reasonably new, and entered the lexicon in the late 1920s:

[image]

Comment: Smells like something that would have first shown up like *I hate your guts, you dirty rat!* in some old James Cagney movie about gangsters.

Comment: It just sounds implausible that so visceral (in very sense) an expression would reach low-class slang from the musty realm of Egyptian archeology.

Comment: @gmcgath: since when has common sense had anything to do with etymology? Also, we've already got lots of ancient Egyptian words in common use: Pyramid, Obelisk, Gypsy, Gum, Ebony, Oasis, Ivory, Ammonia, Barge, Embark, as well as probably Paper, Alchemy, Chemistry, Basalt, Myth, Pitcher, the list goes on.

Comment: @Matt; claiming the word *gypsy* is ancient Egyptian weakens your (somewhat tenuous) thesis to breaking point. Is *Frenchman* from Old French?

Comment: @TimLymington: Are you serious? "gypsy" derives from the Greek word for Egyptian ("Aigyptos") meaning the River Nile, which is itself ultimately derived from the Egyptian word "Hakaptah" meaning "temple of the soul of Ptah" (which is Memphis in Egypt).

Answer (score -3):

I have a theory that the phrase comes from one of the two characteristics of Kosher animals which requires an animal to have more than one stomach. If an animal has non-Kosher-style stomachs (i.e. like a pig) it is not-Kosher (and sometimes seen as not pure).

Perhaps insulting someone's guts was a way of saying they are like a pig, or other impure animal.

Comment: @Downvoters Come on, it's not a bad theory