# Can "hate your guts" imply positives?

Tags: meaning-in-context

The phrase "I/you/he/she just hates/your guts" seems to be defined in most dictionaries as "feel a strong hatred for someone". But is it sometimes related to "to have guts" meaning to have courage or other positive meanings?

([related question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/110458))

Yet I also see usages that are ambivalent, such as these examples from [41 famous quotes and sayings about Hate My Guts you must read](https://quotestats.com/topic/hate-my-guts-quotes/):

- "Despite the fact that you hate my guts and sometimes you're a bit of a bitch. I guess I find that oddly attractive. - Author: Michelle Rowen"
- "There's nothing worse than falling in love with a person over and over every time you lay eyes on them, especially when you hate their goddamn guts - Author: Tiffanie DeBartolo"
- "Let me say, on behalf of the entire gay male community, we hate your fucking guts 'cause you landed him. Share, you selfish bastard. - Author: Andrea Speed"
- "But if I've done something wrong there's no "ifs" and "buts"
  Cause I love you just as much as I hate your guts - Author: Elvis Costello"

I have always thought that it can also mean to "hate that someone has the guts to do something", so in a way being envious of a persons attributes or actions. Because "having guts" can mean to "have courage".

[This Quora answer](https://www.quora.com/What-does-I-hate-your-guts-mean-So-I-know-if-someone-has-guts-or-is-gutsy-they-are-confident-and-bold-Does-this-phrase-mean-I-hate-your-confidence-or-boldness) says:

> [...] It would very rarely mean "I hate your confidence"; e.g. if you were in the military and reprimanding some officer for being overly aggressive, you might say "I hate your guts" and have it mean that

Also, when it means "strongly hate", what is the nuanced difference to just saying "hate me/you/them" or "despise"/"detest"? Is it actually stronger, or weaker (in that syntactically the target of hate is redirected from a person to a body part)? Or maybe just more adequate for humorous use because it's more colorful?

Comment: In the US, *hate your guts* is never *you've got guts*. Your every example is love-hate, and *hate your guts* is the hate part.

Comment: It can be positive: if your best friend does something rather smart, saying "I hate your guts" probably doesn't mean literally. You might do if they weren't your best friend, but are actually rather impressed.

Comment: AFAIK it's just a crude/colourful intensifier - 'I hate you right through to your insides'. I don't think it's related to _to have guts_.